# SpringBoot connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am learning on Spring boot to insert data into MongoDB and encountered some issues. Please give me some of your advise, thank you.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.onboard.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>onboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    MongoService db;
        
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public User createNew(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("role") String role){
        User obj = new User(name, role);
        User newObj = db.save(obj);
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

**MongoService.java**

```
@Service
public class MongoService {
@Autowired
    MongoRepository repo;
            
    public User save(User u) {
        return repo.save(u);
    }
}
```

**MongoRepository.java**

```
public class MongoRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;
    
    
    public User save(User e) {
        if(e != null) {
            template.insert(e);
        }
        return e;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    //@Field("name")
    private String name;
    
    //@Field("role")
    private String role;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public User(String name, String role) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public User() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I tried to use PostMan and did the following setting, but couldnt reach the UserController. The result from Postman is always 404, NOT FOUND.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the annotation `@RequestMapping("/")` also on class level since Spring requires a mapping for your class also, not only the method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
```

Also you have

```
@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("role") String role
```

but in Postman you pass `name` and `role` in JSON body. It is not coded to work like this. You should pass `name` and `role` as query parameters in Postman.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for highlighting on the Query Parameter. If I want to pass by JSON body, how should I get the JSON body in the Spring?

Comment: With `@RequestBody MyParameterObject myParameterObject` instead of where you currently have the `@RequestParam` annotations and also you need to define a class as `MyParameterObject` that has fields `String name` and `String role` and also getters and setters.

Comment: `MyParameterObject` can have every name that you want. I provided just an example

Comment: I got it and understand. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @xxestter please accept the answer if it has helped you solve the problem. You can always upvote as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
        @Autowired
        MongoService db;
            
        @PostMapping("/create")
        public User createNew(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("role") String role){
            User obj = new User(name, role);
            User newObj = db.save(obj);
            return newObj;
        }
    }
```

it is better to use swagger you can get endpoints easily.